# I can't add solr_php extension to php

Tags: php, apache, solr, pecl

Can you help me? I can't add `solr_php` extension to php, I use WAMPSERVER with php 7.2.4 and solr.7.5.0.
when I run my file the error below shows up:

> Class 'SolrClient' not found in C:\wamp64\www\SolrPhp\facet_001.php.

Comment: please explain what exactly you tried to add the extension, provide a [mcve] so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you fulfill the [system requirements](https://php.net/manual/en/solr.requirements.php) for the extension, have downloaded the Apache Solr extension and put it in the `extensions` directory. Then you must add this line in the global `php.ini` file:

```
; In your php.ini file
extension=solr
```

Restart your server and you're done!